# Does armv7 u-boot use MMU?

Tags: u-boot

We are using a Beaglebone black based custom board. I edited a linker script file to add section of memory to log some information there:

```
. = ALIGN(4);
.logging :
{
        _log_begin = .;
        _log_end = . + 0x2000;
}
```

I defined the array in the C file as follows:

```
char log_arr[0x2000] __attribute__ ((section(".logging")));
```

Now if I print `log_arr` address, it outputs `0x8ffa2774`, but when I check the `u-boot.map` file, I see `log_arr` is at the address `0x8084b774`.

Is u-boot using MMU? As far as I know it's turned off in the assembly-written startup code. When I try to use `_log_begin` in the code by defining it as `extern`, u-boot code compilation breaks and throws the error:

> make[1](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/243816/): *** [checkarmreloc] Error 1

When I search for this error I get some [patch](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/243816/) which says "ensure u-boot only uses relative relocations". What does this mean?

Comment: As this question involves programming, it's probably better suited to [so] ([Embedded Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70800/embedded-systems-programming-and-design?referrer=ugotaNldoh5JOVkcEm-iDw2) would be best but it doesn't exist yet). Please don't repost, but you may flag your question to request a migration.

Comment: you are right, i flagged question for migration, Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is u-boot using MMU?

No.
From the README file of U-Boot 2014-07:

```
U-Boot runs in system state and uses physical addresses, i.e. the
MMU is not used either for address mapping nor for memory protection.
```

The difference in the address values from the linker map compared to the runtime value is probably due to U-Boot relocating itself (higher in memory, closer to the top).
Again from the README file of U-Boot 2014-07:

```
After booting and sizing and initializing DRAM, the code relocates itself
to the upper end of DRAM.
```

> ... which says "ensure u-boot only uses relative relocations". What does this mean?

Your code could try using absolute (non-relocatable) memory locations, or else allow C to allocate and relocate the array (i.e. remove the section specifier).

Comment: Thank you for reply, you are absolutely right. Just one EDIT, array allocation with section name (.logging) is not throwing error, only if i use `_log_begin` to get absolute physical address it throws error. I am able to use array address and it still works fine.